# Display page contain in index.php file

Tags: pages

I use following code to display page in a index.php file of template but doesn't show page content.

```
<?php
    $parent_page_content = get_the_content(1677);///my_page_id
    echo $parent_page_content;
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "doesn't show page contain", can you rephrase or re-word it?

Comment: excuse me ..dont display the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
get_the_content( $more_link_text, $stripteaser )
```

`get_the_content` does not take a post ID as a parameter, it always refers to the current post.

Also, don't use magic numbers or hardcode post IDs into your theme, it will break after an import/export or migration.

Instead use `get_page_by_title`, which is not as bad:

```
// get the post
$post = get_page_by_title('page or post title', OBJECT, 'post' );
// filter its content
$content = apply_filter('the_content', $post->post_content );
// display it
echo $content;
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to modify in code :

```
<?php
$post_1677 = get_post(1677); 
$contents = $post_1677->post_content;
echo $contents;
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works and is different from the original?

Comment: you are wrong. because he want to display the page content which page id is 1677. i am right but moderator block me i don't know the reason.

Comment: I'm a moderator, and you have not been blocked, you've just been downvoted. Your code does do exactly what the OP wants, but you haven't explained how your answer is different from what he was doing, so it's difficult to learn from it without just copy pasting. Longer answers get more upvotes, super short ones tend to get downvoted, but that doesn't stop you making edits and additions :)

Comment: i don't know the reason but it not allowed me to answer now.

Comment: That can happen if you get a lot of downvotes, a good chunk of the system is automated, but you're still able to edit your existing answers and ask new questions, earning reputation should resolve that, as would having a single stack exchange account. Comments aren't really the place to discuss this though, if you've further questions then the meta site or chat would be the place to get answers

Answer (score -1):

```
$id = get_the_ID();
$post   = get_post( $id );
echo $output =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?